# How to refresh loaded textures

Tags: image

I am working on a scene, and using CrazyBump to export Displacement and Normal maps; I want to tweak the textures, but currently I need to restart Blender before they update.

Is it possible to refresh them, without restarting Blender?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With the texture displayed in the *UV/image editor*, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or *Header > Image > Reload image*:

[image]

There is also a refresh button on the source selector for any image datablock. **In the node editor, the full datablock settings are in the Properties region.** To reveal this region, place your mouse over the node editor view and press <kbd>N</kbd>:

[image]